# Is there a name for "more and more"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In the statement "Hollywood was looking more and more like a Toys 'R' Us outlet", is there a name/term given to the "more and more"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words *more and more* in this phrase are an adverbial phrase. Being adverbial, they describe the verb, which is to say, they describe *the way in which* Hollywood was *looking like a Toys 'R' Us outlet*.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/increasingly) gives the phrase *more and more* as synonymous with the  adverb *increasingly*:

> **increasingly**
>
> adverb
>
> *To an increasing extent; more and more.*

Comment: I was about to post "increasingly" myself. +1.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an adverbial since "more and more" is more than one word?

Comment: Yes, I agree "more and more" is better described as an adverbial phrase. Will edit.